# How to download large file using post request in angular 6

Tags: angular, file, post, download, angular6

I want to download a large file using a post request.
I need to add some authorization headers,So i want to use post request

```
 this.http.post(request).subscribe(
            (response: HttpResponse) => {
                var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
                hiddenElement.href = 'data:'+contentType+',' + encodeURI(response.body);
                hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
                document.body.appendChild(hiddenElement);
                hiddenElement.click();
                document.body.removeChild(hiddenElement);
            },
            err => {this.log(err); console.log('error is ', err); },
        );
```

I am using above code snippet to download file.
It works fine for small file but not for large files.

Here response is not passed to observer function until the entire data is fetched from server.

So it does not immediately opens a popup to save file and then fetches data(which is commnly expected behaviour)
Instead it fetches entire data and then popup to save file occurs and then contents are saved.

So i want the popup to occur and file download to start immediately after the server sends response headers and status code before fetching entire data

Comment: Specifics for the size of large files

Comment: It will be around 2 GB

Comment: Use [Streamsaver](https://github.com/jimmywarting/StreamSaver.js/blob/master/README.md) lib to download that size, check support aswell the table shown there seems out of date now.  Not sure what youre refering to pop-up...

Comment: This library does not support internet explorer. Our project need to support IE.

Comment: Chrome opens a popup to save file before starting download...I am referring to that popup

Comment: Is it possible to support IE and achieve this ?

Comment: Haven't tried, try with the test part by adding polyfills required